# How to obtain variance of a random variable that depends on a hypergeometric variable?

Tags: variance, random-variable, hypergeometric-distribution

I have been given the following problem:

> In an assembly line production of industrial robots, gearbox
> assemblies can be installed in two minute each if holes have been
> properly drilled in the boxes and in nice minutes if the holes must be
> be redrilled. Twenty gearboxes are in stock, 2 with improperly drilled
> holes. Five gearboxes must be selected from the 20 that are available
> for installation in the next five robots.
>
> i) Find the probability that all 5 gearbox will fit properly.
>
> ii) Find the mean, variance, and standard deviation of the time
> to install these 5 gearbox

I had no problem with the part (i), however, I was not sure about part (ii), so I checked the solution and I didn't understand where they got the variance of time from. This is the solution:

[image]

Any help to understand this will be appreciated.

Comment: "*nice* minutes"? Do you mean "nine minutes" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes to install each gearbox is 2 minutes if it is properly drilled and 9 minutes if it is not properly drilled. So for any arbitrary gearbox, it takes 2 minutes at least, with an additional 7 minutes if it is improperly drilled. Thus if $Y$ is the number of improperly drilled gearboxes, the time it takes to install 5 gearboxes is
$$T = 10 + 7Y.$$
The variance would then be
$$\mathrm{Var}(T) = \mathrm{Var}(10 + 7Y) = \mathrm{Var}(7Y) = 49\mathrm{Var}(Y).$$
(I'm using the properties of variance: $\mathrm{Var}(X + a) = \mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(aX) = a^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)$ for any random variable $X$ and constant $a$.)

The variance of the hypergeometric random variable $Y$ is $$\mathrm{Var}(Y) = n\frac{r}{N}\frac{N-r}{N}\frac{N-n}{N-1} = 5\frac{2}{20}\frac{18}{20}\frac{15}{19} = 0.3552632,$$
so the variance of the time $T$ is
$$\mathrm{Var}(T) = 49\mathrm{Var}(Y) = 49(0.3552632) = 17.4079.$$
The standard deviation is the square root of the variance, so $$\mathrm{SD}(T) = \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(T)} = \sqrt{17.4079} = 4.172277.$$

Note: From the way the solution for part (b)/(ii) is written, it seems like each gearbox would take 1 minute if it is properly drilled and an additional 9 minutes if it is not (so a total of 10 minutes if it is improperly drilled). This is not the information I inferred from the statement of the problem.

Edit: For the proof of the variance of a hypergeometric random variable, go here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistics/Distributions/Hypergeometric